# When is it important to use @MockBean and not @Mock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I found the following information on the subject

- @Mock is analogous to mock()
- @MockBean is a kind of @Mock wrapper that adds a mock to the context
- @MockBean is used in controllers. These controllers have the @WebMvcTest annotation.

But still, when should you use @MockBean and not @Mock?
Why add a mock to the context? For speed of work due to reuse?
What will change if you use @Mock instead of @MockBean in the controller?
@MockBean can only be used in a controller? Why?

Comment: A `@MockBean` is injected by spring into other beans in the context to replace whatever you don't want to be real in the context, a `@Mock` can basically only be used directly in your test. And "@MockBean can only be used in a controller" is not true (e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-mockito-mock-mockbean#spring-boots-mockbean-annotation)